# Delete duplicates with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, window-functions, sql-delete

I have the table `contacts` which contains duplicate records:

```
id name is_contacted created_at
```

I need to delete duplicates, but keep the first record(among the duplicates for each name)  where is_contacted=1.
If among the record duplicates there are no records where is_contacted=1, just keep the first one.

This is what I have so far:

```
DELETE c1 FROM contacts c1
INNER JOIN contacts c2 
WHERE
    c1.id > c2.id AND 
    c1.name = c2.name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `is_contacted`'s data type is `BOOLEAN` and `id` is the primary key of the table and this is the column that defines the order and which row should be considered *first*, use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to rank the rows of each `name`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY is_contacted DESC, id) rn
  FROM contacts
)
DELETE t
FROM contacts t INNER JOIN cte c
ON c.id = t.id
WHERE c.rn > 1;
```

`ORDER BY is_contacted DESC, id` returns the rows with `is_contacted = 1` at the top (if they exist).

For versions of MySql prior to 8.0, without support of CTEs and winow functions, use a join of the table to a query that uses aggregation to get the `id` of the row that you want to keep:

```
DELETE t
FROM contacts t 
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT name,
         COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN is_contacted THEN id END), MIN(id)) id         
  FROM contacts
  GROUP BY name
) c ON c.name = t.name AND c.id <> t.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query will filter only records what you want.
You didn't mention what is primary key in your table, so I don't know how to join this back 1:1 with your whole table.

But if you are not able to determine primary key, they you can create new table using this query, drop original one and rename it to original one.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY CASE WHEN is_contacted = 1 THEN -999999 else is_contacted END ) AS RN_
from contacts
) c
WHERE c.RN_ = 1
```